# Angular4 "required" attribute is not checked on form submit

Tags: html, angular

My very basic Angular 4 form doesn't validate the input (text) fields with the "required" attribute. Input with "required" attribute should be validated by the browser like the html 5 default behaviour without Angular. Was there any change in Angular 4? The same code worked fine with Angular 2.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #testForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" id="test1" name="test1" [(ngModel)]="test" required>
  <input type="text" id="test2" name="test2" [(ngModel)]="test" [required]="true">
  <input type="text" id="test3" name="test3" [(ngModel)]="test" [attr.required]="true">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Try in this plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Wow7NUhaC0KjHtOfVQ2c?p=preview

Comment: try adding `novalidate` on the form

Comment: It's a good hint! I found out this is the default behaviour since Angular4. It was not the same behaviour under Angular2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it by myself...

There was a change from Angular 2 to 4. Under Angular 4 I have to set the "ngNativeValidate", which was default behaviour under Angular 2.

This will work with the default html5 validator "required":

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #testForm="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
  <input type="text" id="test1" name="test1" [(ngModel)]="test" required>
  <input type="text" id="test2" name="test2" [(ngModel)]="test" [required]="true">
  <input type="text" id="test3" name="test3" [(ngModel)]="test" [attr.required]="true">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

[Corrected Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wow7NUhaC0KjHtOfVQ2c?p=preview)
[Someones reported Angular issue which pointed me to the failure](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15531)

Comment: That's what I said, your question was not clear. You never said you wanted native validation. Please try to be more specific next time.

Comment: what exactly is native validation? are you building an app?

Comment: Native validation is the default behaviour like any normal html 5 form with "required" attribute. So a (modern) browser doesn't submit the form until the input field is filled with a valid input. The browser show you which inputs fields have to filled out.

Answer (score 1):

Change button type to button the form will get submitted thats the problem

```
<button type="button">submit</button>
```

To check the whether the form is valid or not disable the submit untill the form get valid

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!testform">submit</button>
```

Comment: That's just what I want: Make usage of the pre-submit validation in html 5 compatible browsers.

Comment: if your problem sloved accept the answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me but you can disable the button when the form is invalid.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!testForm.form.valid">submit</button>
```